# How to replace URLs in HTML Document using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to remove all URL links in an HTML document to be left with only relative links (instead of absolute), using BeautifulSoup.
For example, I'm trying to build code that would transform this HTML tag from this:

```
<a href="https://www.mertens-stahl.de/berlin/unternehmen.php">
```

into this:

```
<a href="/berlin/unternehmen.php">
```

I haven't come across a solution that works, so my code sample looks like this so far:

```
url = https://www.mertens-stahl.de
html = requests.get("https://www.mertens-stahl.de/berlin/downloads.php").text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
soup.find(url).replace_with("")
```

This yields the error *AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'replace_with'*, so I'm looking for a proper way to solve this. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

this should do the trick

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse
links=soup.select('a[href^="https://www.mertens-stahl.de"]')
for link in links:
    link['href']=urlparse(link['href']).path
```